# WCF - The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf

I am developing WCF service. I have a method returning one object after querying from database.

Currently I am facing a problem, If the user object is filled with data, the web service returns correct json response. But if the user object is not initialized with data from database(data is not present for specific ID). I get following error.

```
"The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive."
```

**Existing Code:**

```
    public static User GetUserById(int userId, string dbConnection)
    {
        var userClass =  new User();
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(dbConnection))
        {
            connection.Open();
            var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("GetUserById", connection);

            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", SqlDbType.Int));
            sqlCommand.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = userId;
            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            var reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                userClass = FillUserObject(reader);

            }
            connection.Close();
            reader.Close();
        }
        return userClass;
    }


    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "GetUserById?userId={userId}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    User GetUserById(int userId);
```

I am unable to find out the reason. Stack trace is not working as well.

Any help?

Comment: Since the issue only occurs if no data is present, you'll need to show us your `FillUserObject(reader)` method. Did you already try to debug your service?

Comment: My user class is containing one datetime object. If I don't pass value in that object than I get this unexpected close error.

Comment: So you probably could solve this using a nullable DateTime?

Comment: Converting into nullable datetime worked. Thanks :)

Comment: Stack trace won't tell you enough, as WCF wrapped it so many times. Please enable WCF tracing and see if the trace shows you the details, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Lex Li for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is inside using statement. You don't have to call connection.Close() explicitly. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: That's just a minor improvement but surely won't fix the OPs actual issue.

Comment: My user class is containing one datetime object. If I dont pass value in that object than I get this unexpected close error.

Comment: Yeap that just a minor improvement, but wanted to left that statement because it might help someone later